# formatting a subset of cells with kable and kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra, formattable

I am trying to become familiar with rmarkdown with a simple task. However, I'm stuck on a basic step in rendering a table. I would like some row/column combinations to be formatted in currency and some in percents. Consider this simplified setup and dataframe, focusing on the percent problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'kableExtra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     group_rows
library(formattable)

year <- c('2014', '2015' , 'pctDiff')
q1 <- c(35288 , 36032 , 0.0211)
q2 <- c(30273 , 29669 , -.0172)
df <- data.frame(year, q1 , q2)
df
#>      year         q1         q2
#> 1    2014 35288.0000 30273.0000
#> 2    2015 36032.0000 29669.0000
#> 3 pctDiff     0.0211    -0.0172

df %>% percent(.[3 , c(2:3)] , 0)
#> Error in as_numeric(x): 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
percent(df[3 , c(2:3)])
#> [1] 2.11%  -1.72%
```

I would like the formatting commands to work in a pipe, but my attempt generated an error. The second attempt produced the formats I wanted but isn't practical since the rest of the df isn't there. (Following a stackoverflow post, I also tried using list and unlist, but came up with the same error.) I couldn't find documentation or examples for changing the format in row/col locations. In gt, the formatting task is no problem but I need to knit the rmarkdown code to something other than html, and gt does not produce pretty tables in either pdf or Word yet. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What about the package ```scales```?

Comment: I did try scales before I posted this. I could not find a way that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this uses `mutate_at` to change only the columns that start with "q".

To clarify the `ifelse`: if the row number of the row is `n()`, then it must be evaluating the last row, as `n()` should contain the numeric value of the number of rows total (in this case, 3).

If you want the columns to be mixed and include either "%" or "$", the columns will need to be character.

If it is the third row, then for the TRUE condition, set `as.character(percent(.))`. This converts the value to a percentage, and makes it a character value.

If it is *not* the third row (i.e., it is row 1 or 2), then it is the FALSE condition, and it sets to `as.character(currency(.))`. Similarly, it converts the value to currency, and then makes sure it is a character value.

In both the TRUE and FALSE conditions, the `.` refers to the starting numeric value (in either `q1` or `q2` columns).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("q")), funs(
    ifelse(row_number() == n(), 
           as.character(percent(.)), 
           as.character(currency(.))))) %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling()
```

**Output**

[image: table with currency and percent in kable]

Comment: Thanks for code and explanation. I needed to load formattable as well to make the code work here. So where would you add a second ifelse statement to address the currency locations (rows 1 and 2, cols q1 and q2)? I tried unsuccessfully. I'm not understanding how ifelse worked in this context since it does not seem to have the "no" to the test option stated. And I'm just overall perplexed why formattable seems to work without changing the target cells to character if it is not in a pipe. Sorry, I'm not expert here obviously.

Comment: Sorry about any confusion. I added `library(formattable)`. I also included currency for the rows that are not the last row, for `q1` and `q2`. I updated the explanation, hopefully to clarify things. It does have a "yes" (TRUE) and "no" (FALSE) conditions, they are just on different lines of code.

Comment: With regards to the last statement, `formattable` will work fine with a single type for a column (percent *or* currency). Then, the column can be of `formattable` and `numeric` and have attributes describing the format (including number of digits, etc.). However, combining *both* percent and currency in the same column would involve different `formattable` attributes which is a problem.

Comment: Thank you Ben, for the added code and the clarification. This makes a lot more sense to me.